# Is there an EventListener in as3 to check when an XML has changed?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, event-listener

I have this PHP that constantly changes an XML.

So... I'm asking, is there an eventlistener in flash that instantly detects change in XML?

What I do currently is to just load the XML again and again and check if something has changed. BUT it takes about half a second to load the XML again (not from cache).

Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is, although I'd be interesting to be proved wrong.

It might be faster to call a PHP script that can check if the XML has been updated and return the XML only if required. That way you only actually load the XML when it's been changed, and assuming the XML is on your server the PHP check will be a lot faster because the XML is local to the script.

Comment: Thank you Shane. :) I'll try that out.